# передача данных между страницами

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public partial class getname 
{
  ArrayList mylist;

public getname()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mylist = listboxload();
    lb_page2.ItemsSource = mylist;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (String S in lb_page2.Items)
        {
            OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<string>(S));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}


private ArrayList listboxload()
{

    return list;
}

public partial class Page1
{
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getname pageFunction = new getname();
    pageFunction.Return += new ReturnEventHandler<String>(OngetNameReturned);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(pageFunction);
}

public void OngetNameReturned(object sender, ReturnEventArgs<String> e)
{
    lb1_page1.Items.Add(e.Result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что [вызов OnReturn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms591159(v=vs.110).aspx) означает выход из функции страницы, остальной код просто напросто не выполнится по аналогии с обычным `return` из функции.

Если хотите что-то вернуть, то возвращайте сразу целиком.

**C# Page**

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
  ...
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    PageFunction1 pageFunction = new PageFunction1();
    pageFunction.Return += new ReturnEventHandler<ArrayList>(OngetNameReturned);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(pageFunction);
  }

  private void OngetNameReturned(object sender, ReturnEventArgs<ArrayList> e)
  {
    var a = e.Result;//какая-то обработка вывода
  }
}
```

**C# Page Function**

```
public partial class PageFunction1 : PageFunction<ArrayList>
{
  ArrayList mylist;

  public PageFunction1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    mylist = listboxload();         
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    ReturnEventArgs<ArrayList> ret = new ReturnEventArgs<ArrayList>();
    OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<ArrayList>(mylist));
  }


  private ArrayList listboxload()
  {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add("1");
    list.Add("2");
    list.Add("3");
    return list;
  }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<PageFunction
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:TypeArguments="col:ArrayList"
    ...
    >

    //Content
</PageFunction>
```

Comment: Проблема с этой конструкцией PageFunction<List<string>>, большая проблема

Comment: Нету метода OnReturn, если записывать таким образом, возможно ли его вычленить как-нибудь не знаю

Comment: @SOFL, я обновил код с учетом использования `ArrayList` вместо моего `List<string>`. У себя Вам нужно будет помимо самого кода, еще подправить XAML определение getname класса. Метод я так понимаю не появлялся из-за несоответствия возвращаемых параметров в `x:TypeArguments="..."`

Comment: Да, теперь видно что возвращается коллекция, осталось только правильно отобразить в контроле. Спасибо

Comment: Если немного переделать логику и возвращать содержимое из другого listbox, в который мы переносим items из первого, как привести содержимое listbox к типу arraylist?

Comment: @SOFL в идеале Вам нужно освоить привязки и использовать в приложении mvvm. А так проще всего работать со свойством `ItemsSource`: `MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyArrayList` и `MyArrayList = MyListBox.ItemsSource as ArrayList`.